# Querying attributes on classes/methods in C#

Tags: c#, attributes

Are there any tools available for querying attributes defined for methods/classes?

It would be nice if it was possible to get a list of methods/classes with specific attributes, no attributes at all, etc.

I can imagine I could do this with reflection, but maybe there's a better way.
I would be grateful if anyone has any idea about it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.NET Reflector`](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is a popular tool that does everything in your question. You could also find the same information using the objects in the [`System.Reflection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Your hunch is right - that's why reflection exists.

You can also use static analysis tools such as [nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) (propitiatory) to query many aspects of any assembly.